# Deployable database Test Methods

Tags: c#, database, testing

I am currently in the middle of creating an app that uses a sql CE database, I have made this database deploy-able with the application, however the problem I'm having at the moment is I need to run TestMethods but this is erroring out when it doesn't find the database as its looking in the "testingProject" folder under debug or release as that is it's Data Directory

```
using (SqlCeConnection sqlCon = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\database.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;"))
```

The code above is my connection string, so I'm guessing that means that the test is running and searching for a database in its own data directory

Any help on what I could do without changing the database connection string, database location and still leaving my application deployable? or am I asking something impossible?

*EDIT*

```
[TestMethod]
        public void TestForReadingFromDB()
        {
            List<string> list = class.readDB();
            Assert.IsNotNull(list);
            Assert.AreNotEqual(0, list.Count);
        }
```

just added in the test method that's currently failing

Comment: How are you initializing the database and seeding data to it for the tests?

Comment: I'm using the test method to test the 'class.readDB()' method i have created, I know the database connection works, I'm using it with a form that's all going well, the main problem is where my TestClass sees "DataDirectory" as I can't change code within the class.readDB() method, it just searches for the database in "DataDirectory" if that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the test project you can override the DataDirectory location using

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", <PATH_TO_DATA_DIRECTORY>);
```

For instance in my app.config file the testing projects I have

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="DataDirectory" value="..\..\Database"/>
  </appSettings>
```

In my test fixture base I have:

```
var dataDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataDirectory"];
var absoluteDataDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(dataDirectory);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", absoluteDataDirectory);
```

This sets the DataDirectory to the folder /Database under the test project folder structure.

Once I drop or create a copy of the database in there I can easily run Integration Tests.

Comment: so how would you set the test projects DataDirectory to point towards another folder? just change to ("DataDirectory", @"C:\...\NewFolder") ?

Comment: When I try that it errors out saying missing source files for the code I commented above

Comment: I am not to sure why it is you are getting errors. The way I do the database tests in have a copy of the database and an app.config file in the test project

Answer (score 1):

this is how I specify the data directory path for testing in my initialize data class

```
public class TestClasse
{
    public TestClass()
    {
         GetAppDataDirectoryForTesting();
    }

    private static string GetAppDataDirectoryForTesting()
    {   //NOTE: must be using visual studio test tools for this to work
        string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        var dirs = path.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

        var appDataPath = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length - 3; i++)
        {
            appDataPath += dirs[i] + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString();
        }

        appDataPath = appDataPath + "[foldername(i.e. in my case project name)]" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString() + "App_Data";
        return appDataPath;
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void SomeTestMethod()
    {
        ....test code 
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would this be returned to?

my original code needs to stay as it is from the first line of code above, but the testing class needs to call the method which contains that code and have it still look for and find the same database?

Comment: In my test class I call my initializedatabase class which seeds the database with test data.  In your case you can put it at the top of your test class.  I'll try to modify the answer to show this.   you may need to modify the connection string.  I'm using EF so it is a little different than straight ado.net

Comment: I'm getting a "There is no source code available for current location" error, I'm guessing its what you were saying to do with you using EF?

inside the disassembly the code has stopped on '0000006a  nop' within TestingClass.cs

Comment: Possibly.  I'm guessing that your app_data folder is actually in another project as well.  Try hard coding the absolute path rather than the relative path like my code gives.  If that doesn't work, try adding an app.config file to your test project and load your connection string there.   Not sure if it will work but worth a shot.