# Test project can't connect to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, app-config, configuration-files

I'm not sure but I think my connection string is incorrect.
Here is the situation.
I have a test project with tests. In the test project the app.config file contains the same connection string as the one I'm using for the main mvc app web.config file. It looks like this:

```
<add name="GiftExchangeEntities" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\GiftExchange.mdf;Initial Catalog=GiftExchange;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

but when I run my test inside the test project I get this exception:

> Test method GiftExchange.Tests.DataLayerTests.GiftTests.GetAll threw exception: 
>   System.Data.DataException: An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot attach the file 'C:\TFS\GiftExchange\GiftExchange.Tests\bin\Debug\GiftExchange.mdf' as database 'GiftExchange'.

So I know this is incorrect becauser this is not where the GiftExchange.mdf file is located! It's located in

> C:\TFS\GiftExchange\GiftExchange\App_Data\GiftExchange.mdf

How can I change the path in the config file to point to the mdf file in App_Data without using the full explicit path in the config file?

Comment: Do you have a `Web.Debug.config` doing anything? Does the application pool have the correct security credentials to access `App_Data`?

Comment: You need to tell it where DataDirectory is. Check out this answer... http://stackoverflow.com/a/10799450/3199781

Comment: @AnthonyChu +1 I just noticed that the two directories are quite different, `GiftExchange` vs `GiftExchange.Tests`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the app pool has access. I don't have anything in web.debug.config, just web.config and app.config for the test project. Yes the directories are different, GiftExchange is the main mvc project path and GiftExchange.Tests is the test project. I tried putting "AttachDbFilename=..\..\..\GiftExchange\App_Data\GiftExchange.mdf" into the app.config file connection string tag to get it to point to my database, but the compiler doesn't translate the ..\..\..\